# Python: import failing in installed python custom package

Tags: python, python-module, pypi

I have a python package created using setup.py and then installed in a virtual environment. The directory structure is:

```
root
 |
 +-- setup.py
 |
 +-- package
      |
      +-- __init__.py
      |
      +-- main.py
      |
      +-- common
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           |
           +-- helper.py
```

I have a method that exist in `helper.py` and importing in `main.py` by `from common.helper import func`. After creating a wheel of this and installing and using that as a global module I am getting an import error for `common`. But changing the import statement to `from package.common.helper import func` works. Is there a way to define the `common` as a local submodule to `package` so that even if is installed as a package it uses `common` as a local submodule.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `from .common.helper import func`. You code is failing because it cannot recognise common as a package globally, since it is subpackage to `package` directory.

Comment: But I while running main.py it throws an error. This change would resolve when package is installed but when I want to use the package as aws lambda function it won't allow relative imports

Comment: It would allow relative imports. You will have to create a layer for this package and upload to `Lambda`.

Comment: And moreover since main.py is a module in package , you cannot trigger it directly. Thats what modules are for. Rather, you should create a new file and then import from main module.